# What is the meaning of the green and red Asian dragons?

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures, symbolism, dragons

A member of my family gave me a scroll with a green and red Asian dragon. Is this particular dragon from a myth in Asia? Or does it have a symbolic meaning?

Answer (score 3):

The Azure Dragon or Blue-Green Dragon (靑龍 Qīnglóng), or Green Dragon (蒼龍 Cānglóng), is the Dragon God of the east, and of the essence of spring. His proper name is Ao Guang (敖廣 or 敖光), and he is the patron of the East China Sea.

The Red Dragon (赤龍 Chìlóng or 朱龍 Zhūlóng, literally "Cinnabar Dragon", "Vermilion Dragon") is the Dragon God of the south and of the essence of summer. He is the patron of the South China Sea and his proper name is Ao Qin (敖欽).